# jquery plugin size and slice not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, size, slice

I'm creating a jquery plugin for sorting and pagination a table (I know that there are loads of them and I tried a lot om them, but none so far fits my needs.)

Anyway, I have a lot of tables on my page and call my plugin with:

```
$('.data-table').tableSorterTwo();
```

Here is the plugin code:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.tableSorterTwo = function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            countRows($(this));
            hideRows($(this));
        });     
    };

    function countRows(element)
    {
        console.log($(element).find('tbody tr').size());
    }

    function hideRows(element)
    {
        $(element).find('tbody tr').hide().slice(0, 5).show();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The weird thing is that size and slice are working unexpected and I can't pin down way.

I have this table with 6 rows; `countRows` returns 18. This happens for all tables. The result is the amount of rows multiplied by 3. Why is that?

Als the result of `hideRows` is unexpected. I want to show the first 5 rows of the table; but now (for every table) only the first 2 rows are displayed. Changing 5 to 10 results in 4 rows being shown.

Were are my errors? Messing with this for some time now, but I'm completely lost at the moment and every help/hint/suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tra9N/ Correctly logs `6` to the console. You sure you didnt have your selector as `tbody td`? A table with 6 rows and 3 cells each would read `18` and only show the first 2 lines in `hideRows`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, I believe that Stack Overflow has been your [teddy bear](http://compaspascal.blogspot.co.uk/2007/12/teddy-bear-principle-in-programming.html) and the mere act of asking this question has lead you to fix it.

I can [demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Tra9N/) that your code behaves as expected using the selector `tbody tr`, however the slight mistake of changing the selector to `tbody td` [exhibits the behaviour you describe](http://jsfiddle.net/y3ZxL/) in the question for a table of 6 rows and 3 cells per row.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed Stack Overflow was my teddy bear here (really nice concept, will definitely bring a teddy bear to work tomorrow!). I pasted a table in the jsfiddle and discovered that the error was in the generated table. The <tr> tag were not properly closed. By fixing that My problem was resolved. Since I'm the only developer here it's easy to overlook simple things like this and there isn't a developer (or teddy bear) to let me think outside my own created box for a second. Thanks again!